# Consultas con entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql

necesito hacer una consulta simple en un login.

La consulta seria de ver cuantos empleados hay registrados, si no hay empleados registrados mostrar un mensaje para luego registrarlo.

gracias

```
public partial class WPF1_Login : MetroWindow
{
    STKDB bdd = new STKDB();
    Funciones fn = new Funciones();

    public int empleados;

    public WPF1_Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private async void MetroWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (empleados == 1)


        {
            string msj1 = "No hay empleados registrados";
            Btn_Aux.Content = "Crear Usuario Administrador";
            await fn.Crear_MensajeAsync(Grd_Cont, msj1, 1000);
        }
        else if (empleados == 0)
        {
            string msj1 = "Empleados es 0";
            Btn_Aux.Content = "Crear Usuario Administrador";
            await fn.Crear_MensajeAsync(Grd_Cont, msj1, 1000);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Qué has intentado hasta ahora?

Comment: Debes compartir lo que llevas realizado para poder ayudarte

Comment: Ya coloque el codigo que utilice para la consulta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deberias usar el contexto de `entity framework` para consultar la tabla d empleados, algo como ser:

```
private async void MetroWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    STKDB bdd = new STKDB();
    int empleados = bdd.Empleados.Count();

    if (empleados == 1)
    {
        string msj1 = "No hay empleados registrados";
        Btn_Aux.Content = "Crear Usuario Administrador";
        await fn.Crear_MensajeAsync(Grd_Cont, msj1, 1000);
    }
    else if (empleados == 0)
    {
        string msj1 = "Empleados es 0";
        Btn_Aux.Content = "Crear Usuario Administrador";
        await fn.Crear_MensajeAsync(Grd_Cont, msj1, 1000);
    }
}
```

la idea es que el contexto lo definas local donde vayas a usarlo, entonces accedes a la propiedad que mapea con la tabla de empleados y realizas el `Count()` para conocer la cantidad de registros

No se porque evaluas un valor `== 1` como que no hay empleados, pero bueno, eso imagino dependera de tu logica

Comment: Como recomendación general, de preferencia hay que usar un bloque "Using" para liberar la conexión una vez que se termine de utilizarla. using (var bdd = new STKDB()){     }